# How to define a constraint implying covariant derivatives in XTensor/XAct?

Tags: tensors, constraint, xact

I have two manifolds: `M` and `M1` with metrics `g` and `g1`.

Each metric has a covariant derivative (`CD` and `CD1` respectively).

I want to specify `CD1[μ][g[α, β]]` 
(The result of applying the covariant derivative of M1 to the metric of M).

How can I achieve this or, at least, work it out in a clever way?.

Thanks.